# Does picking a language to learn really matter? They all use similar techniques to solve problems?

Tags: c#, java, c++

College student about to major in CS. Just want to know if it really matter what language you learn first?

Seems to me CS and the nature of our work is about problem solving. Different language seems to differ in syntax, libraries you can use, etc. etc. But when it comes down to it, if you know how to solve a particular problem in one language, you could do it in other languages as well right? I mean surely some languages are better tools and can do a more elegant job, but at the end of the day the ideas are still the same right?

Comment: OP: have a look around on SO, try to understand why some of us are voting to close your question.  You might have better luck at programmers.stackexchange.com or whatever it is called.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Wasn't it better to migrate the question there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what language you use. The **algorithm** underneath is the main thing that matters.

Comment: At the same time, I think we can't really ignore the importance of the language. Idiomatic use of C++ is totally different from Java if used correctly. If we're using the language only as a tool to learn algorithms, I'd agree. If we're planning to get jobs using the same language, we need to focus on how to use that language effectively. I grow wary of developers who use multiple languages but in a lowest common denominator fashion. Languages are rich with idiomatic usage, and that's what helps promote safe designs that build on existing concepts that others can maintain.

Comment: @stinky472: I get what you're saying. When it comes to getting jobs, we need to know how to use a few languages. But looking at it from a student's perspective, I say we need to focus more on the concepts and problem solving rather than the language themselves. Languages keep changing with more and more newer efficient languages coming into the scene. But the core concepts remain eternal. There's no use in knowing a language if you don't know how to solve the problem, right?